# how to assign value to a state hooks after fetching data from firebase firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have two components in `<OpenShippingInvoice /> <OpenUnit />` and i am creating an application  which is generating a bill of cars. I am fetching the data of cars from firestore **cars collection** and I take chasis number from user to select a specific car and my car selection function work successfully but i want to a do another thing which i am facing problem.

My car selection function works like

```
  const [chasis, setChasis] = useState("");
    
  const addCar = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        async function fetchCar() {
          const request = await db
            .collection("cars")
            .where("chasis", "==", chasis)
            .where("stock", "==", "1")
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
              setCar(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
            );
    
          return request;
        }
        fetchCar();
    
        // assign the >>>car[0]<<< to >>>vehicle<<< useState
    

      };
```

My car data is store in **car** State but at the same time i want to add the same car i fetch from db in **vehicle** state

```
    const [car, setCar] = useState([]);
    const [vehicle, setVehicle] = useState({});
```

how can i assign **car[0]** value in vehicle **useState** after fetching value from firestore in **addCar function**
(the reason i use ***car[0]*** is that **chasis** is unique identifier of cars in **cars collection** and it will return only single result if the chasis number match with the document or it will return nothing )

My Link for code is [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-rgb-fpwo8?file=/src/OpenUnit.js)

if my message is incomplete then please ask me
it will be more helpful if changes are done in given link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` to do that. By adding a dependency, your useEffect will be triggered only after the dependency changes, so :

```
useEffect(() => {
  setVehicle(car[0]);
}, [car]);
```

will set you `vehicle` state with `car[0]` after `setCar(...)` is done.